# IPv6: Are There Actual Differences Between Local Addresses ::1 and ::ffff:127.0.0.1?

Tags: ipv6

Couldn't find a clear answer to this question here or on Google. What are the actual functional, assignability, routability etc. differences between IPv6 addresses `::1` and `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, if any?

When should you use one and not the other? If they are equivalent, why two of them?

Answer (score 3):

- `::1` is an IPv6 address
- `::ffff:127.0.0.1` is an IPv4 address expressed in [IPv6 notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861107/69683).

So the two different IP addresses map to two different protocols.

I've never seen the `::ffff` notation used in the wild.

Comment: Server applications that use one socket (IPv6 with V6ONLY=0) receive both incoming IPv4 and IPv6 connections on the IPv6 socket. In those cases IPv4 source addresses are represented using the `::ffff:` notation.